# System lockout, SAM error 12294 

Tags: windows-server-2003

We are facing a login issue due to a SAM error with the error code 12294.

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source: SAM
Event Category: None
Event ID: 12294
Date:
Time:
User:
Computer:
Description: The SAM database was unable to lockout the account of due to a resource error, such as a hard disk write failure (the specific error code is in the error data) . Accounts are locked after a certain number of bad passwords are provided so please consider resetting the password of the account mentioned above.
```

Comment: Grrr don't make me Google the error message, please *actually include it in your question*.

Comment: Also, I just Googled "event 12294 sam" like everyone else will. This might not be the error you're getting, which is why it's also **so important** to include the actual error text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you provide precious little detail, I can only really tell you what I think when I Google for `event 12294 sam` and read the error message that comes back.

According to [KB887433](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887433), you may have a computer on your network which is infected with the W32.Randex.F worm, or one of its variants.

Also, the text of the event itself suggests a possible hardware issue with your disks. If you can run SMART checks or other diagnostics on your disks, identify if one is failing and replace as necessary.